# MYSQL query select exclusion

Tags: mysql

i have this MySql table (scores):

```
id  userId  gameId  score1  score2  idPaisesL   idPaisesV
59  1       11      1       1       229         173
57  1       11      1       0       229         173
58  1       11      2       1       229         173
56  1       11      2       2       229         173
53  1       11      7       7       229         173
52  1       11      3       5       229         173
51  3       11      6       6       229         173
50  3       11      6       6       229         173
49  3       11      5       5       229         173
48  1       11      5       0       229         173
47  1       11      2       3       229         173
46  1       11      1       0       229         173
23  1       1       5       3       173         52
54  1       11      2       0       229         173
```

i want to select only the last result of every userId with gameId = 11
how can i do this? help plz.

Comment: I wish MySQL supported windowed functions.

Comment: Most people would use a select query, but that's just a guess... Show what you've attempted and we'll try to help fix it. We don't write the whole thing for you.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: do you have index?, you need to explain better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    scores AS t
    JOIN 
        (
            SELECT
                MAX(t2.id) AS maxID
            FROM
                scores AS t2
            GROUP BY
                t2.userId
        ) AS Latest
        ON t.id=Latest.maxID
WHERE
    t.gameId=11
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming here that `id` is always increasing for new entries and "last result" is the entry with the highest `id` for that user/game combo:

```
SELECT *
FROM scores a
WHERE gameId = 11
  AND id = (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    FROM scores b
    WHERE a.userId = b.userId
      AND a.gameId = b.gameId
)
```

This may not be the most performant, because MySQL tends to have issues with sub-queries in my experience.

---

If you were using another database that had OLAP Functions, you could do it something like so ([sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2b12e/2)):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT s.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userID, gameID ORDER BY id DESC) AS RN
      FROM scores s)
WHERE RN=1
  AND gameID=11
```

Answer (score 1):

If by "last" you intend the one with the highest id:

```
SELECT *
FROM scores s1
LEFT JOIN scores s2 ON s1.userId = s2.userId AND s1.id < s2.id
WHERE s2.id IS NULL
    AND gameId = 11;
```

No subquery, nice performance, good pattern to learn :)

Comment: That is a good pattern, would never have thought of that, even though I now remember doing it years ago, just always easier to think of the subquery these days